# How do I trigger the events surrounding Leonhard?

Tags: dark-souls-3

I've defeated three of the four Lords of Cinder, which is when I expected Leonhard to

> kill Rosaria

based on what I've read on the [Fextralife wiki](http://darksouls3.wiki.fextralife.com/Leonhard). However, he still hangs out at Firelink shrine encouraging me to invade all I like. Are there other prerequisites to cause him to leave Firelink Shrine? I have a theory on what it might be, but I don't want to try it in case it beefs up someone else's quest.

> My idea is to offer Rosaria one Pale Tongue, but I don't want to make Sirris mad at me for that, since I still want to summon her for some fights.

Comment: have you killed Darkwraith in High Wall of Lothric?

Comment: @arghtype yes I have, and I have the Red Eye Orb in my inventory

Comment: Also, if it makes a difference, I am on PS4 and still on v1.03.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to trigger Leonhard's appearance at Rosaria's Bedchamber, you need to do the following (**this will invalidate Sirris's questline**):

1. Travel to the Rosaria's Bedchamber bonfire
2. Either equip the Rosaria's Fingers covenant item OR offer Rosaria a pale tongue
3. Refresh the zone by sitting at the bonfire

After you have done that, Leonhard should appear in the room. There is no known way to get Leonhard to appear at Rosaria's Bedchamber before Sirris's questline is finished without breaking it.

After Sirris's questline is finished,  i.e.

> When Sirris is found dead at Hodrick's grave

you can perform the aforementioned steps without any negative consequences.

Comment: I appreciate the edit, as a part of me wondered what actually is considered as "finishing her quest". If I could, I'd upvote again. :)